# No cache file written in TensorFlow dataset

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to manage a large image dataset, that does not fit in the memory, while requiring some specific calculation. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
  files  = [str(f) for f in self.files]
  labels = self.categories
  batch_size= 32


  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: zip(files, labels),
        output_types=(tf.string, tf.uint8),
        output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([]), tf.TensorShape([]))
  )

  dataset = dataset.map(
        lambda x, y: tf.py_function(_parser, [x, y, category_count], [tf.float32, tf.uint8]),
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE,
        deterministic=False)

  dataset.cache(filename='/tmp/dataset.tmp')

  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10*batch_size, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)

  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size, drop_remainder=False)

  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        dataset.repeat(None)
  else:
        dataset.repeat(1)

  dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

The `_parser()` function opens a image file, does a bunch of transformations, and returns a tensor and a 1-hot encoded vector. The caching step does not seem to work properly, however:

- There is not significant improvement of the computation time between the 1st epoch and the following ones
- No cache file is created during the process, although the swap partition is almost full (~90%)

Does the `cache()` function creates a file only when both the memory and the swap partition is full? Furthermore, I expect to read only `batch_size` files at a time. However, it seems that all files are read at once during the mapping step. Should I consider using `interleave()` combined with `from_generator()` instead? Or maybe should I batched the files first, then map them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is **not true that lots of RAM is needed to cache**.

As opposed to other libaries (like `gensim` or [`hugging-face`](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/dataset-map-creates-lot-of-cache-files/20719)), **Tensorflow's basic caching is simplistic**, by the design choice. As of now (checked under version 2.12) it uses RAM excessively and doesn't handle garbage collecting well. This snippet demonstrates that *caching consumes RAM linearly* with the data size and *doesn't freeze resources in the second epoch*:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import psutil

IMG_SHAPE = (224,224,3)

def gen_img(shape=IMG_SHAPE):
  while True:
    img = np.random.randint(0,256,size=IMG_SHAPE)
    lab = np.random.randint(0,10)
    yield (img,lab)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
      gen_img,
      output_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=IMG_SHAPE, dtype=tf.int32),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32)
      )
)
# !rm ./my_cached_dataset*
ds = ds.take(int(1e4)).cache('./my_cached_dataset').repeat(2)

for i,(img,lab) in enumerate(ds):
  if i%1000==0:
    print(psutil.virtual_memory())
```

This gives the following results on Google Colab

```
svmem(total=13613314048, available=11903979520, percent=12.6, used=1375707136, free=9484337152, active=541478912, inactive=3288244224, buffers=42360832, cached=2710908928, shared=2764800, slab=214601728)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=11349929984, percent=16.6, used=1927380992, free=9098743808, active=538705920, inactive=3477790720, buffers=42557440, cached=2544631808, shared=2772992, slab=236298240)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=11246673920, percent=17.4, used=2030444544, free=8296189952, active=539701248, inactive=4435984384, buffers=43372544, cached=3243307008, shared=2772992, slab=266022912)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=10702491648, percent=21.4, used=2574770176, free=6455230464, active=543043584, inactive=6231724032, buffers=43421696, cached=4539891712, shared=2772992, slab=300105728)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=10379468800, percent=23.8, used=2897776640, free=4922003456, active=543133696, inactive=7728226304, buffers=43446272, cached=5750087680, shared=2772992, slab=334139392)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=10069651456, percent=26.0, used=3207753728, free=3356516352, active=543207424, inactive=9257857024, buffers=43511808, cached=7005532160, shared=2772992, slab=369360896)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=9731747840, percent=28.5, used=3545501696, free=1802670080, active=543256576, inactive=10778898432, buffers=43560960, cached=8221581312, shared=2772992, slab=403521536)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=9435697152, percent=30.7, used=3841613824, free=266637312, active=543305728, inactive=12278542336, buffers=43610112, cached=9461452800, shared=2772992, slab=438865920)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=9271164928, percent=31.9, used=4006137856, free=193994752, active=543870976, inactive=12340707328, buffers=43122688, cached=9370058752, shared=2772992, slab=440442880)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=8968581120, percent=34.1, used=4308578304, free=169992192, active=543911936, inactive=12344811520, buffers=42754048, cached=9091989504, shared=2772992, slab=435945472)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=8662331392, percent=36.4, used=4615012352, free=169848832, active=543952896, inactive=12350521344, buffers=42803200, cached=8785649664, shared=2772992, slab=428064768)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=9466744832, percent=30.5, used=3810525184, free=163422208, active=543965184, inactive=12362956800, buffers=42827776, cached=9596538880, shared=2772992, slab=416862208)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=9460772864, percent=30.5, used=3816542208, free=155451392, active=543985664, inactive=12395225088, buffers=42835968, cached=9598484480, shared=2772992, slab=382918656)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=9467899904, percent=30.5, used=3809370112, free=160645120, active=543797248, inactive=12427423744, buffers=42835968, cached=9600462848, shared=2772992, slab=349220864)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=9470406656, percent=30.4, used=3806834688, free=161198080, active=543805440, inactive=12460277760, buffers=42835968, cached=9602445312, shared=2772992, slab=315473920)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=9479843840, percent=30.4, used=3797512192, free=161202176, active=543797248, inactive=12491632640, buffers=42835968, cached=9611763712, shared=2772992, slab=291315712)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=9487978496, percent=30.3, used=3789242368, free=166912000, active=543797248, inactive=12523065344, buffers=42835968, cached=9614323712, shared=2772992, slab=262230016)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=9505796096, percent=30.2, used=3771478016, free=183492608, active=543797248, inactive=12555304960, buffers=42835968, cached=9615507456, shared=2772992, slab=229867520)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=9550958592, percent=29.8, used=3728154624, free=183087104, active=543797248, inactive=12567662592, buffers=42835968, cached=9659236352, shared=2772992, slab=215998464)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=9558626304, percent=29.8, used=3720568832, free=190627840, active=543797248, inactive=12567326720, buffers=42835968, cached=9659281408, shared=2772992, slab=215982080)
```

In an attempt to make up for these shortcomings, Tensorflow has **released a more advanced cache-like operation** called `snapshort`. But it is, of now (July'23), experimental and poorly documented.

Answer (score 3):

Note that **cache()** should be used when the dataset is small. If the dataset is large(which is in your case) RAM will not be sufficient to cache its content so it does not fit into memory. Either you should increase the capacity of RAM or adapt some other method to speed up the training.

The other reason for the slowdown of training is the preprocessing stage when you use `map()` function.
`map()` method applies a transformation to each item unlike `apply()` method applies a transformation to the dataset as a whole.

You can use the `interleave()` and retain the same order of `map()` and then `batch()`.
You are already using threading by making `num_parallel_calls` and setting it to `tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE` makes the best use of whatever is available.

You can also normalize your input data and then `cache`, if it does not fit into memory again then it's better not to `cache` on a large dataset.

You can follow [these](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/performances) performance tips from TensorFlow.

If you have multiple workers/devices it will help you to speed up the training.

Below is the sample illustration showing prefetching with multithreaded loading and preprocessing.

[image]